# how to see if value entered is a number and not chars?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to know if someone entered a number and if they did the program continues but if they didn't the program terminates.

```
int main(void) {
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    /*If input is not a number than terminate*/


    /*Otherwise continue*/
    else {
        if (test_prime(i))
            printf("Prime.\n");
        else
            printf("Not prime.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the user enters "hello" than I want program to terminate.

Comment: check the return value of [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) .. it returns "_the number of input items successfully matched and assigned_"

Comment: Have you checked the `isdigit()` solution provided here? The solution is wrong in case of multidigt numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the right way to do it will be something like this

```
int main(void) {
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if( scanf("%d",&i) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input, input is not number");
        exit(1);
    }
    /*input is a number */
    
    if (test_prime(i))
       printf("%s\n","Prime.");
    else
       printf("%s\n","Not prime.");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Checking the return value of `scanf` will help us know whether the `scanf` call was successful or not.

Alternatively you can use `fgets()` to get a line input and then parse it and check with functions like `strtol` etc.
**Checking whether the input is a correct number with only applying `isdigit()` on it is not a solution.**(As provided in other answer). You can check by giving an input `1234` and you will see the `isdigit()` solution fails here though it shouldn't.

To give you an idea why the `isdigit` solution won't work, from 7.4.1.5 standard we can see the quote

> The `isdigit` function tests for any decimal-digit character.

And the decimal digit characters are `0`,`1`...`9`.

#### Explanation of the solution provided:

If you look into the return value of the function it says

> the function returns the number of input items assigned, which can be
> fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early
> matching failure.

This is what is being checked. And this works for multiple digit number also.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what yano described, you will need to set your scanf function to a integer variable, which will count the number of successful scans. Here, you are looking for one successful scan: if integer c is not 1, then return a message saying "invalid number", etc.

```
int main(void) {
 int i;
 int c;
 printf("Enter a number: ");
 c = scanf("%d",&i);
 if(c != 1) {
     printf("Invalid number");
 }
 else {
     printf("%d",i);
     return 0;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We have a function isdigit() to identify the variable and the code goes like this:

```
int main(void) {
   int i;

   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&i);
   if( isdigit(i) ) {
      printf("It is a digit.");
   }
   else {
      if (test_prime(i))
        printf("Prime.\n");
      else
        printf("Not prime.\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your solution with input 1234

Answer (score 1):

Use isdigit() from  **ctype** header file

This function will return 0 if the entered value is non numeric character.

In Your Case,

```
#include<ctype.h>
if(isdigit(i)==0)
{  // Terminate 
}
else
{  if (test_prime(i))
          printf("Prime.\n");
   else
        printf("Not prime.\n");
}
```

For More reference Visit 
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isdigit

Comment: If `i` comes from `scanf("%d",&i);`, `if(isdigit(i)==0)` is **not** a proper test to see if input was a non-numeric character.